# Filter to values in collection in one query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
List<string> Types = (List<string>)Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727")
                                   .Where(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Contains("Microsoft"))
                                   .ToList<string>();
```

How could I modify this so it can only get the values stored in a collection, without writing another LINQ query (which I assume will impact performance?)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> Types 
    = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727")
        .Where(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Contains("Microsoft"))   
        .Where(x => yourCollection.Contains(x))
        .ToList();
```